# PHP - Compiling FreeTSD Extension for MSSQL

Tags: php, compilation, compiler-errors, phpize

I am trying to install `FreeTSD` on my local `MAMP` install. But I am having troubles compiling the extension for PHP7. The commands finish executing but I have no idea where the `.SO` file is output to.

I have been following [this guide on how to compile PHP extensions for MAMP](http://verysimple.com/2013/11/05/compile-php-extensions-for-mamp/).

Here are the commands I have been executing:

```
cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/includes/php  
./configure --with-php-config=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/bin/php-config

cd /Users/m1/Downloads/freetds-0.95.88/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/bin/phpize
./configure --with-php-config=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/bin/php-config  
make
```

I also get random errors after it finishes executing:

> configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-php-config".

The extension I'm trying to install is [FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/).

This is very odd as it does execute, but with that error.

Comment: Please use tags properly. To answer this question, there is no need to have sql-server knowledge. It is pure php question.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this question. The issue is that MAMP for Mac even the Pro version does NOT support installing extensions. I got this information directly from MAMP support.